# Click image, hide other images and animate image sliding with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Just want to preface by saying this my first post, but definitely a long time reader of these forums, so be kind.

What I'm using:

jQuery and Bootstrap 3

What I'm trying to accomplish

I have 5 images centered in a row. I want to be able to click one of the images and have the following happen:

fadeOut or hide the other 4 images, slide the remaining image to the far left of the row and slide into view another div to use as a container for other content.(I was able to get the code working that changes the content based on image click, just need help with the animation portion).

Here's my JSFiddle for what I've been able to accomplish. Any help outside this question (code etiquette etc.) is appreciated. Only been doing this about 3 months or so now, but having a blast. Still getting use to some lingo so explaining like I'm 5 is ok.

Edit 1: http://jsfiddle.net/eps7tpyd/ Here's something even closer, but the animation for the divs moving to the right seems to only happen for the 1st one and I suspect it's because it's class is the only one changing. The other divs don't require a class change to move left. Because the other ones get hidden, they move all the way left in the bootstrap row.

Edit2: Here's my final solution for anyone else trying (doesn't have the reveal div functionality, but don't think it'll be too hard to do. If I get a chance in the next day or so I'll post it up when I'm done. http://jsfiddle.net/8g9tL5zw/

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('div.container2').hide();
    $('div.roster').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("offset")) {
            $(this).toggleClass("col-xs-offset-1");
            $('div.roster').not(this).fadeToggle();
            $('div.container2').toggle();
        } else {
            $('div.roster').not(this).fadeToggle();
            $('div.container2').toggle();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="container">
    <article class="row roster">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1 roster offset">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/308x560/000/fff" class="img-responsive player" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 roster">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/308x560/0000ff/000" class="img-responsive player" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 roster">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/308x560/800080/000" class="img-responsive player" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 roster">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/308x560/008000/000" class="img-responsive player" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 roster">
            <img src="http://dummyimage.com/308x560/ffff00/000" class="img-responsive player" />
        </div>
        <div class="container2">TEST</div>
    </article>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
article .roster {
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.1s ease, margin 0.1s ease;
    -moz-transition: width 0.1s ease, margin 0.1s ease;
    -o-transition: width 0.1s ease, margin 0.1s ease;
     transition: width 0.1s ease, margin 0.1s ease;
}
.player-info {
     display: inline-block;
     color: blue;
     width: 80%;
     height: 400px;
     position: relative;
     z-index: -1;
     background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Is this closer to what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/qmptpa8f/

Comment: That's a bit closer to what I was looking for, but here's the animation effect I was going for. (just have to get an extra container to show based on hiding the images as in the one you've posted. http://jsfiddle.net/q5y9czn7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've prepared jsfiddle which extends your solutions and hope [that's what You wanted](http://jsfiddle.net/8g9tL5zw/6/)

**My solution Step by step**:

**HTML:**

I added `.content` container after last player (with `.clearfix` to keep it under all container and with some bootstrap grid classes)

```
<br class="clearfix" />
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3 content"></div>
```

Also after each player I added content for this player (simple text and image)

```
<div id="content3">
    This is the content for player 3<br/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt=""/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

With CSS I put:

```
.content {
    background: #dadada;
    height: 286px;
    position: absolute; // to keep it over players from 2 to 5
    top: 0;
    display: none; // hide for start
}
```

I've updated yours two CSS fragments like below (simply add .content class):

```
#player2-col, #player3-col, #player4-col, #player5-col, .content {
    transition: transform .5s linear;
    -webkit-transition: transform .5s ease;
}

#player1, #player2, #player3, #player4, #player5, .content {
    transition: transform .7s ease;
}
```

And of course hide player's content at begining:

```
[id^="content"] {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**
In JavaScript I add one local variable (`$parentDiv`) just for optimization, and two lines of code:

```
// toggle element after each player click
$('.content').toggle("drop"); 

// update main content container with content for specific player
$('.content').html($parentDiv.find('[id^="content"]').html());
```

That's all. Hope it will help :)

Comment: Changed yours to be the answer. This is EXACTLY what I was looking to accomplish!

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I was able to accomplish with using bootstrap for framework and using jquery for animation (I'll look at adding revealing the other container later, since I have a good grasp on how that works) I appreciate all the comments and trying to assist! Here's my final result http://jsfiddle.net/8g9tL5zw/

```
$('.portrait').on('click' , function(){
$('.portrait').not(this).toggle("drop");

if($(this).parent('div').is('#player2-col')){
$(this).parent('div').toggleClass("move-player2");
} 
else if ($(this).parent('div').is('#player3-col')){
$(this).parent('div').toggleClass("move-player3");
}
else if ($(this).parent('div').is('#player4-col')){
$(this).parent('div').toggleClass("move-player4");
}
else if ($(this).parent('div').is('#player5-col')){
$(this).parent('div').toggleClass("move-player5");
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured there might be a way to do that, appreciate the insight!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Web Animations API

Simplest reference: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36

Comment: Yes that was my original thought as well, but I'm not sure how exactly to implement. Right now objects are moving because I'm removing Bootstrap classes. Looking at the animate() functionality seems like I would have to be defining the css. Is there a way I'm not seeing maybe to animate() the toggling of the classes?

Comment: @Kirby I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, In the first jsfiddle I'm seeing that the `col-xs-offset-1' class is affecting the animation somehow. Which I'm confused by because there's no css for it. Also I don't really use jQuery I like to do most things natively.

Comment: as the author has stated, its bootstrap. `col-xs-offset-1` is a class defined in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

from your examples it sounds like you want to hide and show item elements via the filter option. While hiding items that do not match the selected item will be hidden. Isotope would be the best solution http://isotope.metafizzy.co/filtering.html. I would go with the fitRows option because it is ideal for items that have the same height. The biggest advantage of this new function is the elimination of a lot of awkward hoops and tests we would have to go through to achieve the desired result. Isotopy offers silky smooth animation.

For the best step by step help with the install check out http://bootstrapwp.com/?ref=14

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I managed to get a little bit of what I was looking for, but that animation is much smoother, so thanks.